# Swift Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableView with various different cells which have as a textLabel a number which every .1 second increases. Instead of reloading the `tableView` or the visible cells every .1 seconds, I reflected that changing the text would have been more effective, but when I try to do so, the application crashes for the error given in the question's title. This is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OwnedBusinessCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = ""

    return cell

}
```

The timer which calls my function:

```
func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    reloadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.reloadTV), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

My function which "tries" to change the text:

```
@objc func reloadTV() {

    for myIP in (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)! {
        let cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: myIP)
        cell.textLabel?.text = increasingVariable
    }

}
```

Complete error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue
>   multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you
>   really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting,
>   use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index
>   path). Cell identifier: cell, index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is a table view data source method, and not meant to be called directly,
which is what you do at

```
    let cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: myIP)
```

If you want a specific cell then ask the table view for it, not the
data source:

```
for myIP in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [] {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: myIP) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or simpler:

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    // ...
}
```